# Class inherits from interface with extra property causes error

Tags: c#, class, properties, interface

I understand that interfaces don't allow fields. But why can't the class that implements the interface have a property/field. I have tried researching the cause of this, but to no avail. Could someone point me to a resource that can help me.

Can classes only implement the method they inherit from the interface and nothing else?

Here is my code:

```
using System;

interface IDog
{
    void Bark();
}

class Dog : IDog
{
    public int numberOfLegs = 24;
    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof!");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IDog Fido = new Dog();
        Fido.Bark();
        Console.WriteLine("Fido has {0} legs", Fido.numberOfLegs);
    }
}
```

I get the error:

*'IDog' does not contain a definition for 'numberOfLegs' and no extension method 'numberOfLegs' accepting a first argument of type 'IDog' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces can't have fields but they can have properties.

So to fix your issue where `IDog` does not have `numberOfLegs` field/property you can move it to interface:

```
interface IDog
{
    void Bark();
    int NumberOfLegs {get;}
}

class Dog : IDog
{
    public int NumberOfLegs {get {return 24;}}

    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Woof!");
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use `Dog` instead of `IDog` in your code...

```
Dog fido = new Dog();
Console.WriteLine("Fido has {0} legs", fido.NumberOfLegs);
```

Or even cast interface to class, but that will defeat creation of the interface.

```
IDog fido = new Dog();
Console.WriteLine("Fido has {0} legs", ((Dog)fido).NumberOfLegs);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Fido` is declared to be of type `IDog`.

As the error clearly tells you, you cannot use a member that does not exist on the variable's *compile-time* type.

If you want to use a member declared by a derived type, you must change the variable to be of the derived type.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Fido` variable references a `Dog` instance but is still of type `IDog`.

Change the first line of `Main()` to `Dog Fido = new Dog();` or `var Fido = new Dog();`

The first part of the error is relevant here - 'IDog' does not contain a definition for 'numberOfLegs'.
The part about extension methods doesn't apply, but will make sense when you learn extension methods (if you haven't).